# Need to understand output of sqlcmd.exe

Tags: sql-server, windows, sqlcmd

I was advised to make another question, from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674045/need-help-to-make-sqlcmd-run-as-per-requirements

My sqlcmd.exe is invoked with a command of the form -

```
sqlcmd -S .\MYSQLSERVER2008 -U MyUsername -P MyPassword 
-i C:\Database\hugescript.sql > log.txt 2> error.txt
```

Now,

```
log.txt says - Canceling connection. Please wait...
Error.txt says - Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : 
Operation was canceled..
```

How do I find out the cause of the problem and fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try and test connectivity to your server with sqlcmd

```
-- connect to instance with sqlcmd
sqlcmd -S MYSQLSERVER2008 -U MyUsername -P MyPassword

-- attempt to open master
USE MASTER;
GO
```

You should see the text : Changed database context to 'master'

Next type "quit" and then try this

Create a file called c:\test_sqlcmd.sql

Add the following code:

```
:setvar myserver "MYSQLSERVER2008"

:CONNECT $(myserver)
USE MASTER;
GO
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
GO
```

Now execute that script `sqlcmd -i c:\test_sqlcmd.sql`

You should see

Changed database context to 'master'
and
MYSQLSERVER2008

Once we have that out of the way, we can continue our research